# Blueimp jquery uploader slide show from database

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-lightswitch, blueimp, lightswitch-2012

I'm trying to implement bluimp file upload plugin  (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Uploadjquery) in my ligthswtich application
Everything works well, except blueimp-gallery support. 
Is there any way to force blueimp-gallery to get his data from lightswtich database (images are stored as binary data) ?
Or any other way to make slide show for images which are stored in database as binary data?